# Perguntas frequentes que já foram respondidas no SOpt

Tags: debate, respostas, perguntas-duplicadas

Há tempos que os maiores problemas das perguntas novas feitas no SOpt são: só um enunciado; e as que já foram respondidas antes.

O problema é que elas não são exatamente duplicatas, são perguntas que a pessoa quer que resolva só o problema dela. A pergunta não servirá para outras pessoas, e não tem nada nela que ajude o assunto ser melhor localizado.

Costuma ser um problema enorme porque a pessoa sequer coloca detalhes, é tão genérico que uma resposta genérica é mais indicada. E a tentativa de outras pessoas responderem quase sempre resultarão em respostas piores do que já existe. Mesmo que tenha algo melhor, é preferível postar onde já tem outra(s) resposta(s) do mesmo assunto.

Muitas vezes a pessoa reclamará que não é duplicata justamente porque não tem uma solução para ela, tem apenas apenas todas informações necessárias para entender o problema e ver como solucionar. E isso atende o interesse de um Q&A. Não atende um mural de helpdesk, então está dentro do objetivo do site.

Por tudo isso fechar como duplicata não é o ideal, apenas apontar onde tem o que ela precisa aprender depois de fechada por um motivo melhor parece ser mais adequado. E de fato vem acontecendo.

O objetivo desta postagem é criar um repositório de perguntas que contém boa parte dessas perguntas recorrentes que são helpdesk de algo que a pessoa deveria aprender.

A ideia é que todos colaborem com assuntos que costumam ver com alguma frequência no site e onde tem a resposta para facilitar os usuários mais ativos acharem o que já existe, alertar a todos que essas perguntas já possuem solução de alguma forma e até mostrar para os novatos que nos importamos com organização.

Então fique à vontade para postar os assuntos que acha que são muito relevantes que possuem uma resposta canônica e que as perguntas precisam saber (não necessariamente quando há fechamento de uma pergunta).

Se não tem uma resposta canônica ou não sabe quais são as melhores canônicas deixe sem referências, e fica o alerta para que a informação canônica seja criada no site.

Além disso nos locais onde tem algo mas ainda não está completo você pode responder para completar o assunto, um conjunto de respostas pode ser canônico.

- [Elemento fora da faixa / Index out of range](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8676/137387)
- [SQL Injection](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8677/137387)
- [Objeto Nulo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8675/137387)
- [Imprecisão dos números de ponto flutuante](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8678/137387)
- [Problema com buffer](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8682/137387)
- [Passar variável do JS para o PHP](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8680/137387)
- [Problema de cast](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8685/137387)
- [Falta referência quando compila com C](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8681/137387)
- [Formato inválido digitado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8683/137387)
- [Criar objeto a partir de um JSON / Ler dados do JSON](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8679/137387)
- [Erro de tipo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8684/137387)
- [Regex](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8686/112052)
- [Formatação, *parsing* e conversão de datas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8687/112052)
- [Obter o retorno de um *callback* em JavaScript](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8688/112052)
- [Gerar números aleatórios sem repetição/Embaralhar array](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8691/112052)
- [Conversão de texto em número](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8695/137387)
- [Como transformar scripts em um executável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8696/112052)
- [Números primos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8697/112052)
- [Pegar o valor de um `input` em JavaScript](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8699/112052)
- [Verificar se uma variável é um dos valores pré-determinados](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8702/112052)
- [Mesclar/juntar array(s) de objetos a partir de uma propriedade em comum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8750/112052)

Comment: Por favor, ajude fazer a curadoria desta lista.

Comment: Adicionei um índice lingando os tópicos. Espero que esteja dentro da visão desse debate.

Comment: Não sei se é adequado ao objtivo, mas, volta e meia apaerece perguntas que o usuário não tem ideia do problema porque não tem ideia do que é e como funciona HTTP, por exemplo, bloqueado por CORS, códigos de erro como 401, 403, etc. Se fizer sentido esse item, eu fiz [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/383129) há algum tempo que introduz bem o conteúdo, talvez possa ser usada de base pra uma wiki, mas adaptada removendo um pouco do conteúdo. O link do wiki pode ser usado como referência pros usuários

Comment: Existe um problema no mecanismo de busca do SOpt, que gera duplicatas, ela não é muito eficiente, por exemplo a pesquisa: "pegar url da página com javascript" feita no SOpt não disponibiliza o resultado desejado, mas a mesma busca feita no google, retorna como primeiro resultado exatamente o que se deseja, sendo um link que direciona para o SOpt.

Answer (score 8):

## Criar objeto a partir de um JSON / Ler dados do JSON

É muito comum a pessoa ter um JSON e querer um código que pegue esse dado e crie um objeto válido dentro da linguagem dele, ou que extraia determinada informação desse JSON.

O site está cheio de exemplos em várias linguagens (além de perguntas mais conceituais sobre o formato em si):

- [O que é JSON? Para que serve e como funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4042/112052)
- [Por que objetos JavaScript nem sempre são JSON?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/313493/112052)
- [Transformar uma informação JSON em variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177001/112052)
- [Como converter uma resposta em JSON para um objeto em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/706/112052)
- [Deserializar Array JSON em um Array de Objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110771/112052)
- [Acessar dados de uma estrutura JSON](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/369103/112052)
- [Como fazer um objeto dentro de um objeto JSON em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/421978/112052)
- [Como selecionar elementos JSON com Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/396521/112052)
- [Como percorrer um dicionário dentro de uma lista em python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/483978/112052)
- [Conversão de string JSON para objeto Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6046/112052)

Answer (score 7):

## Imprecisão dos números de ponto flutuante

Existem várias que tratam do assunto:

- [Resultado impreciso em cálculo com números quebrados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5642/112052)
- [Divisão matemática precisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38138/112052)
- [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/112052)
- [O que é IEEE 754?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/493487/112052)
- [O que é "zero positivo" e "zero negativo" em tipos float e double?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/260685/112052)

E estas possuem links para várias outras relacionadas e indicações específicas para algumas linguagens e tecnologias.

É útil principalmente [quando envolve valor monetário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5746/112052).

Answer (score 7):

## Regex

Algumas perguntas de expressões regulares (regex/RegExp) são recorrentes, seguem abaixo os assuntos mais comuns:

### Senhas

Ou simplesmente coisas como "*deve ter pelo menos uma letra, um número e um caractere especial*" (ou qualquer outra variação - uma letra maiúscula e outra minúscula, etc).

Já tem [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/342605/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/337924/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/360066/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/377860/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/373574/112052), a maioria costuma ser uma variação dessas, bastando adaptar.

Também há o caso de detectar sequências de X ou mais dígitos/letras (por ex: não pode ter "123" ou "abcd"). Nesse caso, o melhor é **não** usar regex, e ao invés disso iterar pelos caracteres e verificar se cada um é sucessor do caractere anterior (por exemplo, adaptando  [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/536705/112052): em vez de guardar as sequências, bastaria verificar se ela atingiu determinado tamanho, indicando que a senha é inválida).

### Datas

Sobre o uso de regex para validar datas, tem algumas coisas [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/363711/112052) e na segunda metade [desta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/360903/112052), e também há exemplos [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/272539/112052), e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/525209/112052) também.

Mas talvez seja melhor seguir a recomendação [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/272541/112052) e em vez de regex, usar os recursos da linguagem que você estiver usando, que sejam específicos para tratar datas.

### Emails

Sobre o uso de regex para validar emails, tem algumas coisas [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/340617/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/327150/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/365489/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1386/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348859/112052) (este último link tem algumas opções no final, só não recomendo a última regex).

### Procurar palavras/acentuação

É comum querer buscar palavras em um texto, geralmente levando em conta a acentuação, sinais de pontuação, etc.

Depende muito da definição de "palavra", mas em linhas gerais, já tem algo [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/450163/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348269/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401529/112052).

Sobre acentuação, tem [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/525345/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15738/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/467835/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136823/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/456749/112052).

### Caractere repetido

Ou "*detectar se o mesmo caractere se repete várias vezes seguidas*". É basicamente uma variação [disso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/365804/112052), [disso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/324584/112052) ou [disso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156818/112052).

### Valores monetários

Basicamente, são perguntas sobre reconhecer valores como `1.234,56` ou `R$ 10,00`.

Já tem [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/342855/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/388903/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/315784/112052).

### HTML/XML

**Não use regex para manipular HTML/XML**, como já bem explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129557/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/440262/112052), e por último mas não menos importante, [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454). Prefira usar alguma biblioteca específica (toda linguagem possui).

**Obs:** o mesmo vale para qualquer tipo de dados para o qual já existe um *parser* dedicado ou libs específicas, como por exemplo JSON, URLs, etc.

### Telefone

Tem várias perguntas sobre o assunto [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bregex%5D+telefone).

Answer (score 6):

## Gerar números aleatórios sem repetição/Embaralhar array

Pode não parecer, mas são problemas relacionados, já que a solução mais simples é primeiro embaralhar o array e depois pegar os N primeiros números. Esse algoritmo se chama Fisher Yates, e [se fizer uma busca por ele no site, já vai encontrar várias soluções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Fisher+Yates).

Também tem variações como "gerar números da mega-sena", etc. Não importa, qualquer variação que envolva pegar um grupo de elementos aleatórios sem repetição se encaixa nesse caso (sim, "elementos", não se restringe à números, o algoritmo serve para arrays que contenham qualquer coisa).

Algumas linguagens tem isso pronto, outras não. Seguem alguns links relevantes:

- C: [Gerar número aleatório sem repetição em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70384/112052) | [Gerar números randômicos que não se repetem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136206/112052)
- C#: [Sorteio onde o nome não pode ser sorteado mais de uma vez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17783/112052)
- Java: [Java, números aleatórios (sem repetição)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58928/112052)
- JavaScript: [Gerar vários números aleatórios sem repetição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10282/112052)
- Python: [Como limitar a geração de números pseudo-aleatórios a números diferentes de zero e não repetidos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173790/112052) | [Como sortear números de uma lista, de forma aleatória e sem repetições?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/460470/112052) | [Retornar os elementos de uma lista de forma randomizada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/500861/112052)

---

Outra recorrente é como escolher elementos aleatórios de um conjunto, mas com probabilidades diferentes para cada um. A resposta está [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/147884/112052).

Answer (score 5):

## Objeto Nulo

Erros de objetos que estão em estado inválido, tipicamente nulo, mas pode ser alguma outra invalidade. Não importa a linguagem, cada uma tem um erro diferente ou até a forma de acontecer.

A pergunta que mais responde isso é [O que é a NullPointerException e quais são suas principais causas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63617/101). Outras podem ser colocadas aqui com mais especificidade da linguagem.

Um exemplo do que pode aparecer: `Cannot set properties of undefined` e é valor inválido.

Answer (score 5):

## Elemento fora da faixa / Index out of range

Erros como `out of range` ou `out of bounds` ou outros a seguir:

- Cannot read property 'xyz' of abc (Não é possível ler a propriedade 'xyz' de abc)
- AttributeError: 'abc' object has no attribute 'xyz'
- Undefined property: xyz::$abc
- KeyError: “['xyz'] not found in abc”
- NameError: name 'xyz' is not defined
- Property 'xyz' does not exist on type 'abc'

Seja em *arrays*, listas, mapas, dicionários, ou objetos criados de forma dinâmica, podem ter o acesso a um elemento não existente gerando um erro de execução.

A pergunta que melhor responde isto é: [Por que ocorre e como resolver um erro de "out of bounds" ou "out of range" ou algo de tipo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/411417/101).

Answer (score 5):

## Passar variável do JS para o PHP

Ou do JS para outras linguagens. Quase sempre envolve AJAX. Por exemplo: [Carregar PHP dentro de JS é uma boa prática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109685/101). Outros:

- [Enviar form HTML sem o botão submit](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47653/101)
- [Posso fazer o JavaScript escrever PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90095/101)
- [Quando usar e não usar AJAX no envio de formulários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91147/101)
- [Passar variável inteira de javascript para php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/234586/101)
- 

Existe o oposto também, embora a solução seja muito diferente e pode variar mais de acordo com a linguagem, a pessoa quer que o sistema de *template* ou outra forma de geração da página inclua um valor no *backend* para que o HTML use depois.

Answer (score 5):

## Erro de tipo

Costuma acontecer em linguagens de tipagem dinâmica em tempo de execução, bastante comum chamar `TypeError`:

- [Como o PHP lida com a declaração de tipos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/382935/101)
- [TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting (Python 3.4)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51574/101)
- 

Answer (score 5):

## Obter o retorno de um *callback* em JavaScript

Há variações do tipo "*como obter o retorno de uma `Promise`*" ou, de forma geral, como obter o retorno de qualquer função assíncrona cujo resultado é processado em um *callback*.

Geralmente é algo do tipo:

```javascript
var valor;
funcaoQueRetornaPromise()
    .then(function(resp) {
        // valor é setado dentro do callback, usa a resposta da Promise
        valor = resp.value;
    });
// quer usar o valor fora do callback
console.log(valor);
```

A solução sempre envolve usar o resultado dentro do *callback* ou usar `async`/`await`, conforme explicado em:

- [Como atribuir o resultado de uma Promise a uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/379212/112052)
- [Alternativas de encadeamento de funções assíncronas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/140814/112052)
- [Como retornar função corretamente? (Escopo de Variaveis)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/209831/112052)
- [Função Retorna [object Promise]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/382792/112052)
- [Acessar váriavel de uma function em outra function](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/446824/112052)

Lembrando que as respostas não se restringem às tecnologias específicas dos links acima, pois a solução é basicamente a mesma para qualquer caso de função assíncrona cujo resultado é processado em um *callback*.

Answer (score 4):

## Números primos

Em geral são exercícios que pedem para verificar se um número é primo, ou alguma variação (receber um array de números e ver quantos são primos, ou gerar todos os números primos menores que N, ou somar somente os números primos, etc). E a dificuldade é geralmente no algoritmo que verifica se é primo.

Uma [simples busca por "*números primos*"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=n%C3%BAmeros+primos) já vai trazer várias perguntas que provavelmente tem a solução para o seu exercício, e aí basta adaptar para o seu caso específico.

Se quiser, faça a busca incluindo a tag da linguagem (ex: `numeros primos [python]` ou `numeros primos [java]`, etc - o nome da tag sempre entre colchetes, conforme indicado na [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)). Todas as principais linguagens possuem várias perguntas que provavelmente têm a resposta para o seu exercício. Alguns exemplos encontrados em uma busca rápida:

### Python

- [Como gerar 200.000 primos o mais rápido possível em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/231555/112052)
- [Obter a lista de números primos menores que N](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205458/112052)
- [Verificar se número é igual à soma dos quadrados de 4 números primos consecutivos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/441099/112052)

### JavaScript

- [Função para checar se número é primo em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57579/112052)
- [Grandes inteiros e primos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57537/112052)
- [Criar um algoritmo, em JS, para listar todos os números primos menores ou igual a N](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/462432/112052)

### Java

- [Algoritmo de números primos só funciona para o primeiro número verificado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138347/112052)
- [Retorno de números primos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/482914/112052)
- [Numero primo JAVA](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/491553/112052)

### C

- [Testar números primos em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/84040/112052)
- [Algoritmo em C - Números primos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58880/112052)
- [Problema para achar números primos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10379/112052)
- [Problema em checar números primos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44537/112052)

### C#

- [Mostrar números primos em um vetor em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/412410/112052)
- [C# - Números primos aleatórios?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/248415/112052)

---

E claro que tem muito mais, basta usar a busca do site, como já indicado acima (ou refinar a busca para casos mais específicos). Se não tiver na linguagem que você está usando, procure em outras linguagens e adapte, pois o algoritmo é o mesmo. **Salvo raríssimas exceções, seu exercício não é inédito** e com certeza já foi respondido (ou basta uma pequena adaptação do que já tem no site), basta procurar.

> Aliás, a dica de fazer uma busca antes de perguntar [vale para qualquer assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), não somente números primos.

Answer (score 4):

## Verificar se uma variável é um dos valores pré-determinados

Por exemplo, tenho uma string e quero ver se ela é "abc" ou "def".

É comum aparecer perguntas que tentam fazer algo do tipo:

```javascript
// JavaScript
if (string === "abc" || "def")
```

Ou:

```python
# Python
if string == 'abc' or 'def':
```

Isso não dá o resultado esperado, pois na verdade são duas condições diferentes:

- se a string é igual a "abc", ou
- "def" - a própria string é avaliada como "true" ou "false" -> algumas linguagens fazem coerção de tipos e [uma string não-vazia geralmente é considerada "verdadeira"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/271693/112052), ou seja, **sempre** vai entrar neste `if`

> E dependendo da linguagem, isso nem compila (Java, por exemplo, pois a segunda condição não é uma expressão que resulta em um valor *booleano*).

A solução é testar cada condição separadamente, ou ter uma lista de valores e ver se o valor pertence à lista. No caso dos blocos acima, seria:

```javascript
// JavaScript
if (string === "abc" || string === "def")

// ou, se a lista de valores for grande
valores = ['abc', 'def', etc... ]; // incluir todos os valores no array
if (valores.includes(string))
```

Em Python tem [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/353470/112052) que explica em detalhes, mas seria algo assim:

```python
# Python
if string == 'abc' or string == 'def':

# ou, se a lista de valores for grande
if string in ('abc', 'def', etc...): # incluir todos os valores válidos na tupla
```

E em qualquer outra linguagem a ideia é a mesma: ou você testa os valores um a um (usando o operador "OR" entre as condições - e repare que algumas linguagens usam `||`, outras usam `or`), ou você cria uma lista/array/tupla/seja-lá-qual-estrutura-que-a-linguagem-usa com os valores válidos, e verifica se o valor pertence à esta lista.

Answer (score 3):

## SQL Injection

A grande maioria das perguntas que possuem um *query* montada com texto para acessar um banco de dados que são postadas estão vulneráveis ao ataque de SQL Injection. Nem sempre o problema da pessoa é este, mas ela precisa ser informada disso e nenhuma resposta correta deveria ser dada sem mencionar isto:

- [Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/101)
- [Como acontece um SQL Injection?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100729/101)
- [O que é o ponto de interrogação em uma query?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22621/101)

Answer (score 3):

## Falta referência quando compila com C

Geralmente ocorre o erro `undefined reference` em C. Pode ser resolvido assim:

- [Erro "undefined reference" ao compilar em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/239967/101)
- [Compilar projeto com vários arquivos .c no VSCode - Linguagem C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/438906/101)
- [Como faço o link no gcc de uma biblioteca C criada por min?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/469681/101)
- [Error de compilação "undefined reference to `sqrt' " no editor Atom](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/246039/101)

Answer (score 3):

## Problema com *buffer*

Muito comum em função `scanf()`, classe `Scanner` ou outros mecanismos que usam *buffer* de console que acabam não lendo corretamente, muitas vezes pulando a leitura da próxima entrada.

- [Como ler do stdin em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42981/101)
- [Limpeza do buffer do teclado após scanf](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9427/101)
- [Por que o Scanner retorna erro em algo que está dentro do esperado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262976/101)
- [Como usar o scanner do Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30642/101)
- [Linha de código ignorada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/186906/101)
- 

Answer (score 3):

## Formato inválido digitado

Muitas vezes gerando um erro `NumberFormatException` ou algo semelhante. Quase sempre encontrou um formato no texto que não é reconhecido, e cada linguagem tem uma forma de evitar isso, capturando a exceção ou usando alguma outra técnica para que ela não aconteça. Alguns exemplos de como tratar isso em algumas linguagens:

- [Diferenças entre Parse() vs TryParse()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101)
- [Converter String para inteiro em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48846/101)
- [Aceitar somente numéricos no input](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/244764/101)
- [Como verificar se o valor de variável string é numero?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/210010/101)

Muitas vezes o problema é devido a formatos localizados (ex: alguns usam a vírgula como separador decimal, outros usam o ponto), e aí depende de configurações específicas para tal. Exemplos:

- [Ler números usando ponto como separador decimal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/427964/112052)
- [Como fazer o compilador reconhecer o . como separador decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170977/112052)
- [TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting (Python 3.4)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51574/112052)

Answer (score 3):

## Formatação, *parsing* e conversão de datas

Pode ser sobre "formatar data" (ou seja, retornar a data em algum formato específico - ex: dd/mm/aaaa, etc), ou o oposto (*parsing*: recebe uma string "dd/mm/aaaa" e quer transformar em data), ou ainda converter de um formato para outro (ou seja, um *parsing* seguido de formatação).

### JavaScript

- [Como formatar data no JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6526/112052)
- [Como formatar data para o formato dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm usando JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/239813/112052)
- [Como converter data e hora com JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262081/112052)
- [Bug no Javascript que subtrai dia em -1 e adiciona horário em meses+dias com 2 dígitos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/408160/112052)

### Java

- [Como tratar diferentes formatos de data?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/379491/112052)
- [Formatar data no java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/231106/112052)
- [Como obter e formatar data e hora atual?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215050/112052)
- [Como formatar data por extenso?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115559/112052)
- [Formatar datas incluindo o offset](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/475471/112052)
- [Converter data dd/mm/aaaa para yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25197/112052)
- [Converter data de um formato para outro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/462843/112052)
- [Formatação de datas com calendar dd/MM/yyyy](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/72828/112052)

### Python

- [Como formatar datas em python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/330458/112052)
- [Formatar String "28122016" para data "2016-12-28"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/179471/112052)
- [Data e hora atual no formato timestamp com time zone](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/371905/112052)

### C#

- [Como converter data no formato dd/MM/yyyy?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152781/112052)
- [Formatar uma string com hora](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82838/112052)
- [Formato de data c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/289368/112052)
- [Como formatar DateTime em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/222259/112052)

### PHP

- [Como fazer a função date() formatar uma data em português?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8317/112052)
- [Formatar data e hora com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/224948/112052)
- [Converter data MySQL (YYYY/mm/dd h:m:s) para dd/mm/aaaa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51692/112052)

Answer (score 3):

## Conversão de texto em número

è muito comum os dados serem entrados via console ou outra interface com o usuário através de um texto ainda que seu interesse é um dado numérico. Cada linguagem tem uma forma de transformar esse texto em número de forma segura.

#### C#

- [Converter string para float no C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/395289/101)
- [Diferenças entre Parse() vs TryParse()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101)
- [Qual a principal diferença entre int.Parse() e Convert.ToInt32()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90981/101)
- [Como fazer um calculo interno no Textbox?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/525032/101)
- [Lendo informações do usuario](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/140106/101)

#### JavaScript

- [Como converter uma String para Int em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/134453/100416)
- [Qual a diferença de parseInt() e Number()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/180248/100416)
- [Como a função 'parseFloat()' funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10002/100416)
- [Como funciona o operador "+" em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/436572/100416)
- [O que significa NaN no JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92169/100416)

Answer (score 3):

## Como transformar scripts em um executável

Algumas linguagens possuem um mecanismo que une arquivos em um arquivo único que pode ser chamado diretamente, muitas vezes usando um bytecode.

#### Python

- [Como criar um executavel " *.exe" em python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13806/101)
- [Como criar um executável a partir de python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183381/101)

Answer (score 2):

## Problema de *cast*

Um dos erros mais típicos que ocorrem em algumas linguagens é uma variação de `Object of class xyz could not be converted to abc`, ou seja, tentou usar um objeto de um tipo onde esperava outro tipo.

Answer (score 2):

## Pegar o valor de um `input` em JavaScript

Geralmente o erro é porque a pessoa está usando o próprio elemento, e não o seu valor. Ex:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#campo');
// o código entra no else
if (input === 'abc') {
    console.log('certo');
} else {
    console.log('errado');
}
```

```html
<input id="campo" type="text" value="abc" />
```

A solução é usar o atributo `value` (ou seja, `if (input.value === 'abc')`). Já tem resposta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/533247/112052), e em trocentas outras duplicadas, que são difíceis de encontrar porque a maioria tem títulos genéricos como "*meu if não funciona*" - daí a importância de colocar títulos relevantes, pois se o título é ruim, ninguém acha e acaba postando de novo (na verdade até com título bom o problema ocorre porque a maioria tem preguiça de pesquisar, mas aí já é outro problema...)

Answer (score 1):

## Mesclar/juntar array(s) de objetos a partir de uma propriedade em comum

A maioria dessas perguntas costuma ser em JavaScript (mas o algoritmo pode ser adaptado para qualquer linguagem), e sempre é uma variação do mesmo problema.

Geralmente tem-se um array com objetos e deseja-se juntar valores que possuem uma propriedade em comum, como por exemplo:

```javascript
// array inicial
const dados = [
  { id: 1, nome: 'Fulano' },
  { id: 1, nome: 'Ciclano' },
  { id: 1, nome: 'Beltrano' },
  { id: 2, nome: 'Trajano' },
  { id: 2, nome: 'Zé' }
];

// o array acima deve agrupar os nomes que tem o mesmo id, ficando assim:
resultado = [
  { id: 1, nomes: [ 'Fulano', 'Ciclano', 'Beltrano' ] },
  { id: 2, nomes: [ 'Trajano', 'Zé' ] }
];
```

Outras variações incluem: somar valores (em vez de ter um array com todos os valores), ou qualquer outra operação que envolva juntar os valores dos objetos que possuem determinado campo em comum.

No fundo, o problema é sempre o mesmo: dado um array de objetos com propriedades A e B, criar um novo array cujos objetos tenham a mesma propriedade A e os valores de B sejam agrupados (e o agrupamento pode ser um array com todos os valores, ou a soma destes, ou a média, ou um outro objeto que tenha os valores em determinado formato, etc).

E a solução também é a mesma, basta adaptar as respostas [desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/496269/112052) ou [desta outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/493586/112052).

---

Outra variação do problema é ter dois arrays com objetos que possuem alguma propriedade em comum, e juntá-los em um terceiro array, cujos objetos são a junção de todas as propriedades dos dois arrays originais. Algo assim:

```javascript
const users = [
  { id: 1, nome: 'Fulano' },
  { id: 2, nome: 'Ciclano' },
  { id: 3, nome: 'Beltrano' }
];
// mapeia a profissão de cada user (o userId é o respectivo id do usuário no primeiro array)
const profissoes = [
  { id: 10, userId: 1, profissao: 'Marceneiro' },
  { id: 20, userId: 2, profissao: 'Bombeiro' }
  // user 3 não tem profissão
];

// o resultado deve juntar os arrays com base no userId
resultado = [
  { id: 10, userId: 1, nome: 'Fulano', profissao: 'Marceneiro' },
  { id: 20, userId: 2, nome: 'Ciclano', profissao: 'Bombeiro' },
  { userId: 3, nome: 'Beltrano' } // esse pode ou não estar na resposta
];
```

Ou seja, deve-se juntar dois arrays, sendo que cada elemento do resultado deve ser a junção deste com o respectivo elemento nos outros arrays, usando algum campo que eles tenham em comum.

A solução está [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/441261/112052), basta adaptar para o seu caso, mudando os nomes dos campos e a lógica para elementos que não estão em um dos arrays (como é o caso do `id: 3` acima, que não está no array de profissões, e portanto poderia ou não estar nos resultados - a solução do link já indicado é facilmente adaptável para qualquer um dos casos).