# Como tirar a comunidade do buraco que ela se encontra?

Tags: debate

Leio o SOen e outras comunidades do SE há algum tempo. Mais recentemente, passei a fazer perguntas nessa comunidades e também a contribuir com algumas respostas. Acho o formato do SE bem interessante para se divulgação de conhecimento. Hoje tenho como hobby navegar em diversas comunidades apenas para ler as perguntas e respostas.

Sabia também da existencia do SOpt, inclusive que tinha sido a primeira comunidade de idioma não inglês, mas nunca tinha acessado, dado que o SOen supria bem minhas necessidades. Ontem, finalmente, tive a curiosidade de ver como estava a comunidade dos meus colegas falantes da língua portuguesa.

Senhores, o que eu vi foi muito triste.

Não vou ficar aqui remoendo o estado lastimável em que se encontra a comunidade hoje. Isso já foi muito bem discutido [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8706/8-anos-de-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs-recalculando-rota) e [aqui](https://pt.quora.com/Por-que-o-StackOverflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs-%C3%A9-t%C3%A3o-ruim/answer/Antonio-Maniero). Apenas para ilustrar, quase todas as questões [mais recentes com a tag Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) estão negativadas. Isso não acontece em nenhuma outra comunidade SO/SE. Quando a enorme maioria das questões estão "erradas", significa que algo vai muito mal.

Isso me incomodou muito e fiquei algumas horas pensando no que poderia ser feito. A seguir, dou minha lista de impressões e sugestões. Certamente, algumas delas são impraticáveis de serem implementadas. Acredito até que algumas contrariam certos princípios das comunidades SO/SE. De qualquer forma, vou dar minha opinião sem muitos filtros. Não pretendo ofender ninguém e já peço desculpas antecipadamente. Encarem isso como a visão de um outsider.

1. O maior problema, de longe, é a quantidade enorme de perguntas muito genéricas, do tipo "faça aqui meu trabalho da faculdade" ou "esse meu código deu um erro, o que aconteceu?" (as vezes nem a mensagem do erro é incluída na pergunta). Qual a motivação que alguém tem em responder perguntas desse nível? Perguntas genéricas devem ser fechadas imediatamente, e sairem da lista de perguntas o mais rápido possível para não poluirem mais o site. Temos que atrair os bons respondedores e educar de forma rápida os perguntadores.
2. Em quase todas essas questões, um bot solicita nos comentários, acertadamente, que o usuário "edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico...". Acredito que essa mensagem teria que ser mais clara. A pessoa que faz esse tipo de pergunta certamente não entende como o SO funciona. Talvez a pessoa devesse ser indicada para algum local com perguntas exemplares para ela entender a dinâmica esperada. Uma sugestão é um link para uma lista de perguntas mais bem votadas.
3. Falando em bot, não ajuda muito um bot que negativa uma resposta e faz um comentário sem sentido algum, como [esse aqui em uma resposta que eu dei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/542235/como-alterar-adicionar-valores-de-uma-lista-em-um-m%C3%B3dulo-importado/542253#comment973255_542253). Acredito que, no caso, o bot considerou a resposta inadequada por não ter links. Essa é uma heurística muito simplista que vai sinalizar muitos falsos positivos. Se coloquem no lugar do respondente, tendo que navegar nesse mar de perguntas ruins e, quando consegue espremer o que dá de uma questão e elabora uma resposta, recebe um comentário ensosso de um bot burro. É pedir para a pessoa não voltar mais.
4. Sobre o ponto acima, isso cria um ciclo vicioso. Eu tive que ficar "caçando" perguntas para conseguir meus míseros 5 pontos para postar aqui e, quando eu conseguia, o bot tirava meus pontos. Quantas pessoas tinham algo para falar aqui no Meta mas não o fizeram simplesmente porque é absurdamente difícil?
5. Claro que nada do que eu escrevi vai resolver a causa raiz do problema: o baixo nível de educação dos questionadores. Não adianta passar o pano, o problema é esse. A verdade é que qualquer programador mediano entende inglês e não passa nem perto daqui. Temos que de alguma forma tornar o SOpt atrativo para respondedores que falam português. Permitir a proliferação de questões parasitaárias só vai afastá-los.

Da minha parte, assinei o RSS de algumas tags em que eu posso colaborar e vou responder na medida do possível. Não deixemos que isso aqui vire um Yahoo! Respostas.

Comment: Só pra deixar claro, não é um bot que negativa e comenta. Existem as [filas de análise](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review) (o sistema manda os posts para essas filas, cada uma tem suas regras para quais posts aparecem) e usuários com pontuação suficiente têm acesso a elas. Um usuário escolhe uma das mensagens predeterminadas (e também pode, opcionalmente, votar) e a mensagem é postada como se fosse o bot. As mensagens são genéricas e ruins, muitos já reclamaram pra mudar, mas por enquanto é o que tem... De qualquer forma, não é bot, é uma pessoa - esse é outro ponto, o sistema é confuso...

Comment: Quanto ao item 3, o problema é que a pergunta lá não é clara: ela diz que um problema ocorre (sem dar detalhes do erro), mas nos comentários eu coloquei um exemplo mostrando que não consegui reproduzir o problema (ou seja, faltam informações na pergunta). Sendo assim, ela nem deveria ser respondida (o certo é esperar o autor da pergunta esclarecer). Alguns optam por negativar a resposta para "passar essa mensagem" - claro, só quem votou pode confirmar o motivo exato, só estou especulando porque costuma acontecer (de qualquer forma, não foi um "_bot com heurística simplista_")

Comment: Sobre a resposta que fez o link, acredito que o negativo foi porque a resposta não responde a pergunta. Pelo meu entendimento o usuário quer que o conteúdo do arquivo `dados.py` seja mutável. Se usarmos o seu exemplo, pelo que eu entendi do que foi perguntado, o usuário gostaria que ao final da execução do programa em python, o conteúdo do arquivo `dados.py`  seja o que postou. Ou seja um array com 4 elementos e o conteúdo do arquivo atualizado. Mas só quem votou pode confirmar o motivo exato. E essa foi a minha interpretação do que o usuário quis dizer com a pergunta dele.

Comment: Viu só, o @Danizavtz entendeu uma coisa completamente diferente do que eu e vc entendemos. Só isso dá margem pra considerar a pergunta off-topic, por não estar clara (e por isso, deve-se esperar o autor esclarecer em vez de responder). Lembre-se que o objetivo do site é criar um repositório de conhecimento sobre programação, e o conteúdo deve ser útil para todos, inclusive futuros visitantes. Por isso a pergunta deve estar clara, sem margem para múltiplas interpretações (mesmo que algo pareça "óbvio" ou subentendido, não pode haver espaço para ambiguidades)

Comment: Quanto a instruir os usuários, fazemos o que podemos, mas o site ("o sistema") também precisa mudar. Só que a SE (Stack Exchange, empresa dona do site) não tem mostrado interesse. A página de fazer pergunta, por exemplo, foi atualizada há 2 anos e ela deveria ajudar com isso, mas sinceramente, [ela é patética](/q/8246/112052). Propostas para que o site instrua melhor os usuários [existem aos montes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314304/401803) mas nunca são implementadas, a SE deixa tudo para os usuários moderarem manualmente, e isso já se mostrou insuficiente. O resultado está aí...

Comment: Obrigado @hkotsubo e Danizavtz, não tinha consciência dessa regra implícita de que perguntas mal formuladas não devem ser respondidas. É que o atual estado de coisas está tão ruim que eu não consigo achar perguntas que não estejam mal formuladas (ainda não tenho reputação suficiente para comentar, espero mudar isso em breve). Porém mantenho o ponto geral, de que os comentários são muito genéricos e desmotivam o respondente.

Comment: Sim, esses comentários são genéricos e ruins, e já foi pedido pra mudar, mas a SE, como de costume, têm ignorado. Enfim, os problemas que vc apontou não têm uma solução fácil. Há poucos usuários ativos que ainda tentam fazer algo, e estamos no limite porque muita coisa depende da própria SE mudar o funcionamento do site, nos dar ferramentas melhores, etc, mas eles não querem. Tudo que a SE tem feito nos últimos anos deixa bem claro que agora eles se preocupam mais com quantidade do que com qualidade (mesmo que o discurso oficial diga que não).

Comment: @sourcream eu também raramente acho coisas boas para responder, vontade eu tenho. Aqui e ali respondo algo não muito bom, mas que dá para responder. Com tanto "tempo de casa" peguei o jeito do que é bom. Nem sempre outras pessoas concordam.  Meu critério é se posso agregar algum conhecimento para as pessoas. Evito responder para solucionar o problema da pessoa, a não ser que que a pergunta esteja muito boa, e olhe lá. Ajuda o fato da minha experiência aqui também manda uma mensagem: "eu, experiente, vi algo de bom na pergunta, mesmo ela sendo ruim no geral", o novato não tem essa vantagem.

Comment: Respondendo à pergunta do título: se chegar mais gente como você no site, disposta a fazer curadoria de conteúdo, quem sabe tem jeito :) Tem de fato vários problemas atualmente no site, mas eu considero que o mais grave é falta de gente que entenda o espírito do Q&A e esteja disposta a fazer moderação comunitária.

Comment: Olhando o link tem diversas que estão sim corretas e abertas e diversas com muitos problemas e devidamente fechadas, algumas poucas com problemas ainda abertas. Perguntas erradas não são todas, o que existe na maioria são as  com "problemas" e que podem ser "melhoradas"... Me parece que essa minha resposta já responde ao que você precisa entender: [Votos para fechar perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2676/3635)

Comment: O resto que resolve esse problema perguntando é ler [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), inclusive teve uma pergunta recente de [python] mesmo, que o autor escreveu uma série de coisas desnecessárias, eu editei ela deixando só o texto relevante e isolei o código de interesse, basicamente salvando a pergunta, foi muito mais fácil isolar e criar um exemplo Mínimo e Verificável do que parecia, é que as pessoas não querem se dar ao trabalho de praticar fazer o "fácil", a maioria quer suporte técnico personalizado.

Comment: Assim que encontrar o link talvez eu envie aqui. De qualquer forma, me parece que essa pergunta já tem diversas perguntas com respostas aqui no https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ que responde a todas suas dúvidas.

Comment: Vou tentar responder de uma forma resumida, para tirar a comunidade do buraco é só os usuários lerem [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) e os mais experientes participarem, ajudando na moderação comunitária. Sobre perguntas fechadas, elas estão fechadas corretamente e isso já é 50% do problema resolvido.

Comment: Eu gostaria de ouvir as opiniões quem negativou a pergunta – partindo do entendimento de que todos os que comentaram votaram positivo, ou pelo menos não votaram negativo.

Comment: @bfavaretto votei pelos motivos que comentei acima e também é porque o item 2 da pergunta *"Talvez a pessoa devesse ser indicada para algum local com perguntas exemplares para ela entender a dinâmica esperada. Uma sugestão é um link para uma lista de perguntas mais bem votadas"* já é algo que fazemos, tem por exemplo o "Guia" e o terceiro motivo é que a comunidade não esta exatamente em um buraco, tem problemas, mas os problemas não estão relacionados a orientação para o usuário, mas sim sobre a participação de mods comunitários e falta de interesse de muitos em ler as dicas dadas.

Comment: Em resumo, tudo o que foi perguntado aqui já foi debatido de uma forma ou de outra, se tem interesse de tirar a comunidade do buraco, primeiro precisa entender q o buraco real não é pelos problemas q imagina, fora que a pergunta estava baseada em diversos enganos, primeiro que score é fácil de levantar, criar um MCVE é simples de criar, só precisa de um pouco de pratica no começo, já aqueles "textões" focados na "ajuda personalizada" não são exatamente fáceis, na verdade só é meio fácil por algum desespero por suporte, mas complicando para quem responde.

Comment: @bfavaretto ps: se for ficar me explicando só vamos continuar a fazer o q sempre fazemos, ficarmos nos repetindo de coisas que já foram debatidas diversas vezes, q simplesmente o AP poderia ter lido nos links fixados ou nos comentários de dicas q muitos de nós, mods diamante e comunitários, deixamos. É justamente por isso q acho q perguntas assim não ajudam, pq só serve para ficarmos nos repetindo, quase tudo q poderiamos debater sobre problemas comuns já existe no META.

Comment: Entendi, @GuilhermeNascimento, não precisa ficar se explicando :) Eu positivei mais pelo espírito da pergunta – estilo "viva! existe mais gente que entende o formato do site, gostaria de ver um resultado melhor e está disposta a participar!". Independentemente das sugestões oferecidas. Em geral, quem vem aqui discutir o site é quem está nervoso por ter tido pergunta fechada. Ou os mesmos de sempre.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento onde está o guia com perguntas exemplares?

Comment: @sourcream [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/3635). Nesse guia inclui praticamente tudo, até mesmo sobre o famoso [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/3635), [como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/3635) e [perguntas subjetivas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/486/3635). Claro que o guia fala muito mais, mas esses 3, junto com o [help/asking], são os pilares dos problemas e soluções de como atuar no site.

Comment: @sourcream De qualquer forma a pesquisa está ai https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=assunto (trocando a palavra `assunto` pelo tipo de problema que deseja pesquisar de como atuar no site principal)

Comment: @bfavaretto até entendo, se eliminarmos alguns "parâmetros", mas a questão mesmo é que "soluções" já temos, então não temos que ficar discutindo possíveis soluções novamente e novamente e novamente, a não ser que seja algo muito eficiente baseado em ampla experiência de participação do site, entendendo todos problemas comuns, se não é o caso, então é focar no que já existe no META, ler, entender e participar. Não estou criticando, mas dar soluções sem entender e sem experiência não ajuda muito. Uma otima iniciativa recente foi até agora isso: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8674/3635

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento, minha sugestão é dar exemplos de cara, pois pelo nível das perguntas são de pessoas que não vão ler esse guia muito menos usar a busca. No geral, discordo de você, a situação está feia sim e exige maiores discussões sobre o que ser feito. Do jeito que está, o SOpt não sai nem na foto com as outras comunidades. E além disso, sabe o que eu farei com tudo isso que você falou? Ler, abaixar a cabeça e trabalhar para ajudá-los :-) Você e os demais estão há anos aqui e tem todo meu respeito. Vou procurar humildemente contribuir com que posso.

Comment: A situação supostamente feia esta em outros locais e situações e a comunidade não está atrás de outros sites, inclusive sempre que observo somos fonte de pesquisa, mas existem sim problemas e os moderadores fazem o que podem para alinha a comunidade na qualidade barrando os "helpdeskers", mas somos humanos, o que falta são usuários experientes interessados em seguir o modelo, muitos abandonaram o site. Ainda sim não conheço nenhum outro site em português que estejam por cima de nós, ao contrário, vi  em certos fóruns gente usando respostas daqui, essa conversa que somos pior não procede.

Comment: De resto foi o que já expliquei, os problemas específicos e que realmente são os que tentamos resolver foram já foram discutidos, tem postagens especificas, tem problemas além do que você imagina, mas de resto não temos como melhorar todos os pontos, porque muitos deles dependem da comunidade.

Comment: Quando eu disse "outras comunidades", quis dizer outras comunidades SO/SE. Essa é minha referência. Não consigo ver a SOpt no mesmo patamar.

Comment: SE é a rede de todos site e comparar o SOpt com o SOen não faz sentido, o EN sempre será mais acessado, da mesma forma não tem como comparar o SOes (espanhol) com o SOen, nem o SOru (russo) com o SOen, etc. Os sites "primos" do SOen são mais regionais, enquanto o idioma inglês é usado até por quem não domina o inglês, temos 55k de visitas diárias, pode conferir: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJkAa.png - link: https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic

Comment: Bom, agora que entendi que a intenção é comparar, querendo um trafego ou popularidade proximo a algo "mundial", recomendo que leia isso: [Por que (me parece que) o StackOverflow em Português não dará certo?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5654/3635).

Comment: Obsevação: o SOru só tem esse numero elevado de perguntas porque no inicio eles não eram SO, eles eram um site concorrente, os dados foram "portados" para a plataforma da SE assim que a empresa adquiriu o tal site russo, o site se chamava `hashcode.ru` e já existia a um bom tempo (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284185/198279)

Comment: Eu participei aqui por anos na época de 2018, tinha mais de 30k de pontos e acesso pleno as ferramentas de moderação disponiveis a membros que não são moderadores, como o guilherme e o Maniero. Mas o desgaste de ter que lidar com conteudos e principalmente os donos desses conteudos era grande.  Eu pedi exclusão da conta e fiquei um tempo fora, e voltei apenas como membro comum agora. Apesar desse episodio ruim que eutive aqui no SOPT, ainda torço para que o site possa ter seu renascimento, afinal, não se acha conteudo em portugues nessa área tão facil assim.

Comment: Sobre a sugestão de dar exemplos de cara e que as pessoas não vão ler  o help, ou o guia ou qualquer outra dica, já é um indicio que não serão bons usuários para o site e não vai ser "exemplos" que irão mudar suas percepções, pois já falta "compromisso" com o interesse em participar.

Comment: Acho que o @GuilhermeNascimento quer dizer é que não existe uma fórmula mágica para evangelizar um usuário na cultura do site. Tem partir do próprio usuário a iniciativa de dedicar um pouco de seu tempo, antes do uso da ferramenta, a explorar a Central de Ajuda. Na primeira sinalização gastar um tempo lendo as mensagens e os links informados. Nos pedir orientação ao invés de bater no peito dizer que está certo e comunidade está toda errada. É uma questão cultural, as pessoas querem entrar no site e aprender a usar fuçando ao invés de buscar as regras para ler.

Comment: O curioso é que os usuários que possuem conta aqui no SOPT e no conta SOEN. No SOEN não agem da mesma que fazem aqui. Esses dias um usuário deu umas cinco respostas aqui, editei as cinco removendo saudações e agradecimento, esse mesmo carinha no SOEN em inglês não fez numa saudação e nenhum agradecimento e as publicações impecáveis em inglês. Não é um único caso, tem um que está suspenso, quando aparece vem só para causar e fazer o que não pode, no SOEN esse cara é quase um moderador faz tudo certo e aqui o cara parece o capeta.

Comment: Não sei o acontece com as pessoas porque estão usando língua nativa querem montar uma fachada contra-cultural se rebelando ao sistema, só que o sistema é uma pessoa igual a ele dando o seu melhor de graça.

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento então para que existe o guia? Apenas para os previamente "bons usuários"? Porque não me parece que está funcionando e foi exatamente o motivo de eu ter aberto essa pergunta. Exemplos ajudariam pois ficaria mais fácil assimilar.

Comment: @sourcream, o guia existe para ser lido. Se o usuário não se dispõe a o ler ou aos diversos links diariamente repassados nas publicações, ele presume o que é o site e age predisposto a impor uma dinâmica comportamental de onde já esteja acostumado ou tenta fazer o que quer até terminar em um grande desabafo aqui no META onde os comunitários se desgastam reiteradamente o informando tudo o que já foi exaustivamente discutido e quando o mesmo percebe o equívoco, ou descobre que a empreitada não vai ter sucesso, remove a conta e abre outra com outro nome.

Comment: Isso é desgastante, pois ao invés de nos focar no assunto Linguagens de Programação, que é o que nos reúne aqui, a todo o momento temos que ficar ensinado a usarem o site, fazer edições, fechando perguntas, discutindo que o site é assim porque uma empresa determinou e controla o formato e não pode ser do jeito que ele quer,...... Isso cansa, eu não quero moderar eu abro o site para aprender coisas novas, mas vendo a bagunça que estão fazendo não tem como fazer vistas grossas.

Comment: A pessoa que vem ao site hoje só quer uma coisa, seu problema resolvido não importa como e dane-se o resto. Ela não têm um inspiração ou visão altruísta em buscar a solução do seu problema deixando um legado construtivo. Quantos que já vi que quando obtém uma resposta satisfatória aos seus problemas apagam suas perguntas, deixando aqueles dedicaram tempo em buscar a solução no vazio Quantos são aqueles que ao obter resposta nem param para aceitar ou classificar o conteúdo. Quantos que já vi mentindo um *+1 nessa excelente resposta* quando o meu voto era o único.

Comment: @sourcream, agora se você detectou a falta duma publicação mostrando exemplos de boas perguntas para serem imitados. Você tem a total liberdade para criar essa publicação e postar aqui no META. Tenho certeza que sendo uma publicação construtiva vamos todos ficarmos muito felizes em a usar em nossas orientações e trazendo resultados positivos podemos até a indicar ao [FAQ da Comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/699/faq-da-comunidade).

Comment: @sourcream bom, isso é um sinal de que realmente minhas explicações não estão sendo entendidas, vou resumir novamente: o Guia e o Help existem para quem quer ser comprometido com o site, quem veio aqui atrás de "helpdesk" ou "somente score" (para montar um portfólio da vida) e não quer ler entender o espírito da comunidade é justamente quem não tem compromisso, portanto dar "exemplos" não vão resolver a falta de compromisso, quem quer se comprometer tem que se esforçar.

Comment: E outra coisa, ninguém falou de "bons usuários" em momento algum, compromisso não tem haver com ser bom, tem haver com querer se envolver e participar de forma a ajudar não só a si mesmo, mas a comunidade, seguindo os ideias e aprendendo eles a medida que participa, ninguém está exigindo aprender em 5 minutos, a ideia é entender que não somos "helpdesk" e o resto o usuário vai pegando com o tempo, desde que saiba participar e entender o que lhe é orientado quando falhar em algo.

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento eu entendi seu ponto. Só quis contrapor dizendo que, se formos pensar assim, não adianta nem escrever nada pois o usuário não vai ler mesmo. Minha sugestão foi só uma ideia de como talvez facilitar um pouco a assimilação da dinâmica do SO, que pode não ser muito fácil de explicar só com o conceito. A parte dos "bons usuários", eu tirei do que você disse _literalmente_. Mas estamos nos entendendo. Você não acha que a comunidade está em um buraco, mas eu acho. Você não acha que exemplos vão melhorar o que o guia já faz, eu acho. Temos nossas discordâncias.

Comment: @sourcream em contraponto se o usuário não vai ler é porque esse é o usuário não comprometido, ele é desinteressado e quer apenas suporte técnico. Você pode ter esperanças que dar "exemplos" vai ajudar. Estou no site a bastante tempo e posso dizer, nem isso e nem a maioria das coisas tentadas resolvem a falta de compromisso e interesse, quando o objetivo do novo usuário é só buscar o *suporte técnico personalizado*. Dar suporte para eles só vai ajudar a eles como se fosse uma assistência técnica, raramente vai gerar postagens úteis para outros. Não é questão de eu discordar, é de experiência.

Comment: sobre as questões mais pontuais como perguntas em específico já bem comentado, mas é de consenso geral que o **maior** problema é o nível de quem pergunta, ou seja, é como delegar para a escola os que os pais deveriam fazer em casa, cada um tem de ter a sua responsabilidade, não podemos aqui "ensinar" as pessoas sobre pesquisar, tentar resolver coisas por si próprias, uma noção mínima de análise, e pq não tbm de redigir alguma coisa... esse não é o trabalho do SO(em geral), então difícil achar uma forma de ajudar essas pessoas, que chegam com o mindset "vou jogar ali e alguém vai resolver"

Comment: Tem meios de resolver, o problema é a falta de interesse da SE (já comentado). Um dos problemas é que as pessoas vem aqui sendo analfabetas funcionais, não é um problema só da comunidade, é um problema nacional, as pessoas não sabem sequer expressar suas dúvidas de forma mínimamente entendível, depois que fazem a pergunta, não percebem ou não tem interesse de corrigir quando fica bagunçado porque código não está formatado, como já disseram, jogam qualquer coisa aqui querendo que nós arrumemos e respondermos com o que ele deseja, ...

Comment: se tentamos corrigir e instruir a pessoa, alguns ainda ficam brabos e saem xingando ou vem pro Meta reclamar se achando com toda a razão, o que diminui o interesse dos "bons usuários" cada vez mais (eu sou um que praticamente abandonei a comunidade). Também há uma questão cultural de não ler o manual e sair usando, o que dificulta. Mas tem solução, criar um modal com um conteúdo bem breve pra ajudar um pouco na qualidade das perguntas (poucos vão ler de qualquer forma, mas se alguns lerem, já ajuda). ...

Comment: Pedir ajuda pra criadores de conteúdo afim deles criarem conteúdos que instruam o corretamente os novos usuários me parece ser a melhor opção, foi comentado aqui pelo @AugustoVasques, mas é provável que quem tenha interesse nisso, queira cobrar algo, talvez nós mesmos podemos ir atrás das boas almas que aceitem fazer isso de graça. A ideia da [nova página de perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8252/91006) era incrível, mas a ferramenta [é completamente inútil](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8246/91006), se fizesse aquilo que deveria, melhoraria bastante. ...

Comment: Outra solução mais drástica seria impedir que usuário com pouca reputação fizessem perguntas, mas aí, eles precisariam dar respostas, só moveria o problema de lugar, mas ajudaria um pouco, aqueles que só querem um helpdesk rápido (sem ter interesse na comunidade) abandonariam a plataforma sem perguntar nem responder, o que é bom ao meu ver, os mais insistentes eventualmente iriam aprender com os erros e começariam a melhorar suas respostas (talvez seja Inocência minha, também podem ficar martelando no mesmo erro por um tempo até desistirem)

Comment: Já foi esclarecido a questão dos bots, mas queria comentar que o único bot mais inteligente é os comentários no chat das novas perguntas do Meta e, ainda assim, ele leva uns bons minutos pra comentar lá. E sobre isso: "Quantas pessoas tinham algo para falar aqui no Meta mas não o fizeram simplesmente porque é absurdamente difícil?", não é um problema, na verdade é uma solução, muito dificilmente um usuário com tão pouca pontuação vai fazer um post aqui que realmente acrescente algo pra comunidade, provavelmente, a maioria só iria xingar e falar mal achando ter razão

Answer (score 10):

Primeiramente, não estamos aqui para competir ou ser comparados com outras comunidades, mesmo que tenham os mesmos objetivos como o SoEn. O que está acontecendo, em resumo, é que não estão lendo como a comunidade funciona. Por quê?

Eu tenho alguns palpites:

### Preguiça

Provavelmente um dos maiores casos. Eu não quero generalizar, mas de 10 perguntas que analiso, 7 tem um conteúdo precário, que deixa evidente que o autor não dedicou nada para elaborar sua pergunta. Normalmente apenas pegam o código e jogam lá na questão, isso quando ela tem código.

Se isso for uma das causas (se não a maior delas), *não há nada que possamos fazer.*

### Não está claro o que somos

E eu acredito menos nessa. A comunidade lançou o [Guia de Sobrevivência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas?noredirect=1&lq=1) e depois lançou a sua [versão resumida](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8089/guia-de-sobreviv%C3%AAncia-do-sopt-vers%C3%A3o-curta) pro pessoal mais desmazelado. Posso falar que estes guias contribuíram para algo? Eu acho que não. Nós só ficamos sabendo da existência destes guias quando uma pergunta é fechada, e nem sempre o autor se dedica a ir ler e reformular sua pergunta.

### Acham que somos um "suporte técnico especializado"

Você vem, joga a sua pergunta da faculdade e espera que magicamente alguém faça o dever para você. Não fazemos isso, e isso é bem claro nos links que citei acima. O maior problema disso é quando o problema cria o tal do [Problema X-Y](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%c3%a9-o-problema-xy?cb=1), que em resumo é uma pergunta específica demais que precisa de uma resposta específica demais. O conteúdo deixa de ser didático e passa a ser inútil para alguém que quer aprender com o site, deixe de fato de aprender algo.

> Como vou saber fazer um conjunto de esteiras com blindagem anti-tanque, capazes de transportar automaticamente peneiras e cocos até um buraco em cima de uma mesa?

Isso vai filtrar muito as respostas que você receberá, pois:

- É muito específico e complexo
- Muitas condições e detalhes
- Sem paciência pra entender (desde que nem o autor entende o que tá dizendo)

No final, quem iria responder acaba desistindo e vota negativamente na pergunta (com razão, é algo amplo demais ou simplesmente "sem resolução"). Então, o autor da pergunta vai no meta reclamar do site ou até mesmo xingar os moderadores.

Tudo isso poderia ser evitado **se soubesse perguntar**.

> Tenho alguns cocos, mas não consigo tirar a água que está dentro deles. Como faço para abri-los e então coletar a água de coco?

Percebe como a pergunta é mais limpa, legível e clara? Você receberá respostas.

## Tudo se resume a ler

E é simplesmente isso. Quer tirar a gente do buraco? Vamos ler como usar o site, para que ele serve e quando usar. **A comunidade é nossa**, o conteúdo que você coloca aqui tem uma assinatura sua, e tenho certeza que você não quer assinar nada sujo ou com *downvotes*.

Para não fazer nada sujo, leia como fazer bonito, ou melhor, direito.

Tudo bem, nem todo mundo quer ler nada. Acredito que ninguém lê nada afinal, e essa é a maior catástrofe da SoPT. O que vamos fazer? Forçar o usuário a ler e aplicar uma prova final? Isso vai espantar alguns usuários, mas os que ficarem com certeza irão formular uma boa pergunta.

A SE introduziu um novo editor de perguntas, que "analisa" a pergunta antes de enviar ela. Eu acho ela inútil e não muda nada. Se mudasse, a situação do site hoje seria diferente.

Temos que introduzir nossos guias práticos de forma evidente e clara no site, e não somente nos comentários quando acabamos de fechar uma pergunta.

O Tour precisa ser atualizado com o conteúdo que a própria comunidade desenvolveu para ela mesma.

Comment: Se fizermos um video do Guia de Sobrevivência do Stack Overflow no YouTube ou uma dancinha do Tour no Tik tok  todo mundo vai assistir. Tamanha evolução tecnológica para recriar uma antigo flagelo social, a dicotomia dos alfabetizados e os não alfabetizados se expandiu dentro do grupo de pessoas alfabetizadas para os que leem vs os que tem preguiça de ler.