# Podemos (ou devemos) alterar perguntas ruins para que se "tornem válidas"?

Tags: debate

*Isso era uma coisa que queria perguntar e sugerir hà muito tempo. Mas, ocorreu isto hoje, e então estou aqui.*

---

Acho que qualquer pessoa sabe dos problemas do SO: várias perguntas de baixa qualidade, várias perguntas fechadas, votos negativos e sem qualquer explicação (...).

A questão é: em alguns casos não seria possível editar a pergunta para salvar a pergunta?

Em alguns casos, existem perguntas do tipo: "me ajude, tem um problema no meu código". Esse tipo de pergunta é (quase) instantaneamente fechada e negativada. Mas, em alguns casos não daria para editar a pergunta e torna-la válida?

---

Irei dar um exemplo, hoje eu vi uma pergunta como:

- [fala pessoal estou com uma problema no meu código e não to conseguindo resolver, sou novo na programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/553498/2)

Quando entrei nela já havia um -1 e uma edição na pergunta (para corrigir a formatação do código). Mas, a pergunta tinha um código simples (ou seja: dava pra ver o problema, embora o OP não mencionasse quase nenhuma informação), e o problema era reproduzivel.

Eu resolvi responder (da forma mais rápida, antes que fosse fechada). Depois alterei a pergunta para:

- [Por que não consigo definir o valor do input com o innerHTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/553498/3)

Basicamente, alterei apenas o titulo dela, de forma que fique mais claro o problema.

---

O que eu fiz foi correto? Ou eu deveria ter simplesmente votado para fechar?

Se essa edição for válida, não seria possível fazer mais isso? Ao invés de fechar a pergunta, simplesmente altera-la para melhor se enquadrar no tópico do SO? Ou até mesmo, edita-la e depois votar para fechar por duplicidade.

Comment: Não se deve alterar a intenção o autor e também não se deve tentar validar perguntas que são simplesmente erros de digitação. Relacionado: [Baixa qualidade em perguntas de novatos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7165/3635)

Comment: Mesmo se consertar a do innerHTML ainda é duplicata. O fato é que sequer tem fundamento querer mexer value com innerHTML. É o tipo de erro de digitação por falta de leitura de documentação. Eu ajudaria nos comentários nesse caso. Se o usuário estivesse seguindo documentação nem chegaria no ponto de perguntar aqui. O título que pôs é ótimo, só que não é o caso de ser a primeira ocorrência do problema (e a "resposta" seria tipo "de acordo com a documentação(link) innerHTML não é pra isso). Pra resumir: salvar perguntas melhorando tem fundamento, é algo desejável, mas não é para qualquer caso.

Comment: Tem uma "Prima" dessa nesse link aqui https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8699 - provavelmente é o caso de atualizarmos a lista de perguntas frequentes com a versão "innerHTML" (não vou pesquisar agora, mas já vi). Uma alternativa (depois de buscar similares) seria editar a postagem, trocar o código por um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável, e perguntar pro autor se a edição representa a duvida do autor (ensinando a reverter se não for o caso). **Depois** dele confirmar, você posta a resposta para o código já melhorado. Aí a postagem fica útil para bem mais gente, que é o objetivo do site.

Comment: E eu **acho** que essa aqui do meta também já foi discutida, é bom verificar tambem. :D - de qualquer forma, tem vários pontos que tem que considerar que vão alem do que comentei aqui, só quis adiantar parte do assunto.

Comment: Concordo com que foi dito [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8753/137387#comment38346_8753), independente das questões exemplificadas o ideal não é uma validação a qualquer custo, pessoalmente creio que inicialmente a edição deve uma gentileza com usuário novato tornando sua publicação mais legível, uma gentileza com os colegas mais experientes revisando e aprimorando detalhes. No caso de edições mais invasivas penso ser de bom tom deixar um comentário informando o porque das alterações e a possibilidade de reversão.

Comment: Em [Devemos editar uma pergunta que está/será fechada e possivelmente removida?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7946/137387) há uma discussão sobre até que ponto é viável dispender esforços de edição e também devemos ficar atentos com [as perguntas camaleão](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/608272).

Comment: Perguntas que começam com saudações tem uma grande chance de serem fechadas. Não por causa da saudação, mas pelo conteúdo precário que precede a saudação. Há coisas que não valem a pena serem editadas, são perguntas do problema x-y e não canônicas; conteúdo que não vai servir de nada para a comunidade.

Comment: *Ninguém é obrigado a concordar comigo, é minha opinião e opiniões contrárias seriam construtivas e bem vindas pois se relacionam com pergunta.* [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/553371/137387) fiz uma edição invasiva numa pergunta que achei relevante com potencial de atrair visitas ao site e cujo as soluções sejam uteis porém interpretei originalmente a pergunta como mal formulada, possuindo título inexpressivo e mal parecia ser uma pergunta real. Logo após a edição deixei uma orientação junto do porque das alterações e a possibilidade de reversão.